# Php required field

Tags: php, required

I am trying to insert some records but I dont know how to check required fields and form controls.Can you show me how can i check required fields?
I am new in php. Thank you.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) == 1) {
     $ad = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['name']);
     $soyad = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['surname']);
     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email']);
     $q = "INSERT INTO db (name, surname,email) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$email')";
     $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
     if($r){
         $message = '<p>Message Added!</p>';
     } else {
         $message = '<p>Could not add because: '.mysqli_errno($dbc);
         $message .= '<p>'.$q.'<p>';
     }
}
```

Comment: `if (empty($_POST['name']))` etc. ?

Comment: Can you show me on my codes i added but did not work?

Comment: Note that your code is open to **SQL injection**.  You should use prepared statements and query parameters rather than execute user input as code.

Comment: If I will try thank you. But I did not before. First of all i want to check fields but i dont know where is mistake

Comment: @Elizz Try [looking up php form validation](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+form+validation).

Comment: Thank you mike now i am reading i added too but i dont know where is my mistake

Comment: You could pass by ajax, and inform PHP what are your 'required' fields, but be aware you are not safe from abuse. you should do a double check on js and php each separated, also you may add a prefix to required fields and detect those on PHP

Answer (score 0):

Your form and php code will not be aware of the limitation set on your database table. You can ask the database how a table looks using the describe keyword followed by the table name. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/describe.html). The response will tell you which if a field's allowed to be null or not. Based on that you can create your form to take this into consideration.

Comment: I will read but later i am searching just example i read some articles but couldnt success.

Answer (score 0):

In your html You can add `<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" required="required" 
        />`
The `required="required"` makes that field required.

And in your php you can check if that field is empty or not like this

```
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username']!="" ){
    $uname=$_POST['username'];
if(strlen($uname)>=4){
//use your sql insert query .I'll show you how to do it using pdo
$sql=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `yourtable` (uname) VALUES (:u)");
//$conn is your sql connection variable.
$sql->execute(array(":u"=>$uname));
}
else {
echo "please Insert a valid username";
}
    }
    else {
     echo "Please insert an username";

    }
```

Comment: What if I enter an empty string for a username?

Comment: Well in that case I would use  `strlen>=4 or what ever is minimum required`

Comment: Then you should add that to your answer

Comment: Yes I dont know how to do just trying to learn if you help about conditions

Comment: Toni thank you :)  i will try now i know little mysqli knowledge and doing with mysqli if i achieve i will write here

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username']!="" ){` can be simplified to `if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {`

Comment: yeah i would like the approach mike suggested .